# Navigate to a html from button tag

Tags: html, css, angularjs

[image: this is how it looks with working A tag and button tag]i have a ng-repeat with some forms. Each form has a button - Edit Profile which needs to redirect the user to /userProfile with $stateParam(userId).

This is my code:

```
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-grey btn-ripple">Edit profile</button>
```

I tried the follows with **no**  success:

```
 <a href="/userProfile?userId={{staff.UserId}}"  class="btn btn-grey btn-ripple">Edit profile</a>
```

- Works fine but the css doesn't work perfectly on `<a>` tag

I tried to  include the `<button>` tag into the `<a>` one , doesn't work.

I want to make in HTML, no javascript . I tried with `form` tag and `action=url`, doesn't work, he tries to acces an `"http:\\"`url.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: are you using Angular JS?

Comment: Yes, i tried with location.path(url) but the character "?" goes into encoded one, an the url doens't work anymore

Comment: Can you please show us the CSS?

Comment: `Works fine but the css doesn't work perfectly on <a> tag` well then you have to make it perfect.. I think its just some bootstrap css applying some rules.. All you have to do is overwrite the bootstrap css with your custom css..

Comment: Also, use ng-href instead of plain href.

Comment: look at updated question, this are the differences of css when i use A and button tag. The A tag works perfectly but i want to look like button tag

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using AngularJS, you can do:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="location.assign('/userProfile?userId=' + staff.UserId)" class="btn btn-grey btn-ripple">Edit profile</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

So i tried this :

```
   <a  href="/userProfile?userId={{staff.UserId}}">                                      
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey btn-ripple" >Edit profile</button>
   </a>
```

Works perfectly :)